# Can't access oracle APEX page

Tags: oracle-apex

I worked with Oracle apex and created some applications.
the access url was localhost:9090/apex/apex_admin

today I tried to change my book to work-group and changed the IP of my laptop and then restarted it, now I can't access the APEX environment any more although I restore my computer 3 day back but also no way.

note: when I enter this url: localhost in browser it opens IIS7 page.

Please who can help me I am in need to finish my work as soon as possible.

Comment: look's like webserver not catch request. what webserver you use ? you can connect to db from sqlplus ?

Comment: yes I login to Sqlplus without any problem.

Comment: Excuse me !.. I don't know what you mean with webserver that I use. but I am working in windows 7.

Comment: connect to sqlplus as sysbda and execute this `SELECT DBMS_XDB.GETHTTPPORT FROM DUAL;`

Comment: It returns:
 GETHTTPPORT
-----------
       9090
and it is the port that I use to connect.

Comment: ok, u use EPG. try to disable IIS.

Comment: I disabled it and restarted my laptop but also no way.

Comment: it also show you IIS page?

Comment: Yes when I navigate to localhost or 127.1.1.1 it shows a page contain a picture written IIS7 inside it.

Comment: before I get the problem I changed in My pc networkID and set the option
I use this computer as part of business network,, then I chose without domain.

Comment: May the problem be solved if I uninstalled and then reinstalled APEX ?..

Comment: Also can I get my current work-space applications later ?

Comment: i think problem in iis7, try change port to your EPG... from sysdba execute this `exec DBMS_XDB.setHTTPPort(9091);`

Comment: It returns : PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
but that wasn't useful unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you should run some Oracle services.

1. Go to Windows + R (Run)
2. Write **services.msc**
3. Find OracleMTSRecoveryService and both services which are started by OracleOraDb11g.....
4. If it's disabled go to properties and change Startup Type to Automatic
5. Then run this services and refresh browser page.

Hope this will help. It worked for me